# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource and JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String on put method

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am working on a web-based app with angular and spring boot. Jwt is generated and the user can log in and he can see his information but when I want to edit user information it shows this error on the browser:

**user:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

And in IntelliJ, it says: **JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String**

I have used:
httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable()

and

```
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return source;
    }
```

and still got problems updating user information.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*",allowedHeaders = "*")` annotation to the respective Controller class in backend

Answer (score 0):

It is my config you can try it:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }


}
```